# Hiding the "Ready" page in an Inno Setup installer

Tags: inno-setup

I have a little setup project to run vb.net project, installation/setup environment in 32 and 64 bits and inno-setup helps me to run the right version of it. Here is the code, it is short.
My problem is that `DisableReadyPage=yes` still shows the ready to install page. How to get rid of it?

Even if I disable `[file]` and `[run]` sections ready to install page is still there...

```
[Setup]
AppName=xxx Environment
AppVerName=xxx Environment
AppPublisher=zzz
AppPublisherURL=somewebaddress1
AppSupportURL=somewebaddress2
AppUpdatesURL=somewebaddress3
AppID="xxx Environment"
DefaultDirName={pf}\zzz
PrivilegesRequired=admin
DefaultGroupName=xxx Environment
CreateUninstallRegKey=no
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
DisableWelcomePage=yes
DisableReadyPage=yes
DisableFinishedPage=yes
DirExistsWarning=yes
OutputDir=.
OutputBaseFilename="Setup"

[Files]
Source: Unzip.exe; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: deleteafterinstall
Source: Setup.zip; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: deleteafterinstall

[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\UNZIP.EXE"; Parameters: "{tmp}\Setup.zip -d {tmp}"
Filename: "{code:RunInstallExe}"

[Code]
function GetProcessorTypeId (): Integer;
var
  s: String;
  i: Integer;
begin

  case ProcessorArchitecture of
    paX86:  i := 1;//s := 'x86';
    paX64:  i := 2;//s := 'x64';
    paIA64: i := 3;//s := 'Itanium';
  else
    i := 0;//s := 'Unrecognized';
  end;
  Result := i;

end;

function RunInstallExe(Param: String): String;
var
  _path: string;
  _procId: Integer;
begin

  _procId := GetProcessorTypeId();
  if _procId = 1 then
    begin
      _path := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Install86Environ.exe');
    end
  else if _procId = 2 then
    begin
      _path := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Install86Environ.exe');;  //run in wow64 mode
    end
  else if _procId = 3 then
    begin
      _path := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Install64Environ.exe');;
    end
  else
    begin
      _path := '';
    end

  if FileExists(_path) then
    begin
        Result := _path;
    end
  else
    begin
        MsgBox('Installation package not found.', mbCriticalError, MB_OK);
    end

end;
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disablereadypage):

> When Setup is not running silently, this directive is ignored if no other wizard page before the Ready to Install wizard page has been shown yet.

With all of the Disable*Page directives you have, it's the first page that's being displayed.

What is your goal in disabling all of the pages?

Comment: Adding a custom page at the startup will allow the ready page to be skipped too. Adding this to your answer would be a big edit so I'll leave it to you.

Comment: to mirtheil: my goal is this: based on OS and bit version I'll run an installation that will be unzipped and run automatically. I don't need another UI to pop up.

Comment: In that case, you should run the installer silently. Personally, I like to customize any install I run. Trying to hide pages on an installer would make me not want to install the product.